# How to prevent server side validation from running when a button is clicked?

Tags: xpages

I have a required Edit Box in a facet of a dynamic content control. Client side validation is disabled. I want to have a cancel button in this facet that will take the user back to the previous facet they were on. The part I cannot figure out is how to tell the Edit Box to not run the validation when the Cancel button is clicked.

Here is my cancel button:

```
<xp:button value="Cancel" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dc").show(sessionScope.backBtn);}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Here is the required edit box:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.Vendor}" required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired message="Vendor name is a required field."></xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the immediate attribute on true, see example; immediate="true"

```
<xp:button id="buttonCancel" themeId="Button.Danger">
                            <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:language.getLanguageString("button.cancel")}]]></xp:this.value>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true"
                                save="false">
                                <xp:this.action>
                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:executeScript
                                            script="#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState = true}">
                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                        <xp:openPage
                                            name="/languages.xsp">
                                        </xp:openPage>
                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a property in the panel on the lefft where you can select not to run validation for the event of this button.